# SQL Error [42601]: ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a ":" Position: 683

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta com CONCAT, seto os valores que desejo so que retorna erro de sintaxe

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a ":"
Position: 683
```

```sql
select  processador.cd_code,
    endereco.ds_address,
    rdo.nm_lane,
    rdo.dt_record_pass,
    rdo.ds_license_plate,
    rdo.vl_speed|| ' Km/h' velocidade

from tbgen_rdo rdo
    INNER JOIN tbgen_processor processador ON rdo.id_processor = processador.id_processor
    INNER JOIN ( select     lane.nm_lane,
                dctosProc.id_general_processor,
                lane.ds_address
             from tbdctos4x_processor dctosproc
            inner join tbdctos4x_lane lane ON lane.id_dctos_processor = dctosproc.id_dctos_processor
        ) as endereco
            ON endereco.nm_lane = rdo.nm_lane AND endereco.id_general_processor = processador.id_processor
where rdo.dt_record_pass >= to_timestamp(CONCAT(concat($P{PARAM_FILTER_DATE_INI},' '), $P{PARAM_FILTER_HOUR_INI}),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and 
rdo.dt_record_pass <= to_timestamp(CONCAT(concat($P{PARAM_FILTER_DATE_END},' '), $P{PARAM_FILTER_HOUR_END}),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and rdo.ds_license_plate <> '#######'
    $P!{PARAM_WHERE_CLAUSE}
order by rdo.tbgen_rdo
```

Comment: Exclusivamente no PostgreSQL funciona perfeitamente: 
`teste=# SELECT to_timestamp(CONCAT(concat('15/01/2020',' '), '15:37:49'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');`

dá como resultado:
`      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2020-01-15 15:37:49-03
(1 registro)
`.

Comment: Poise, descobri que na verdade não era erro de sintaxe e sim que os valores retornados nas variáveis não estavam no formato da mascara.